# WPF C# RightClicking excludes row from bound DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which has a bound ItemSource to a collection. I have a object, that represents the selectedItem of the DataGrid, bound as well. And i have the wish to change a property of the element, which was rightClicked.
Problem: When I rightClick a row, the selectedItem gets updated after the MouseRightButtonUp Event and so I can't access the clicked row.

Is there a way how I can still preserve the Binding pattern?

Comment: I cant get your question. You want to change a property of the right clicked row before it is the selectedItem? Or do you want to change a property of the actual selected item if you right click on some other row?

Comment: I want to change a property of the right clicked row. But at the moment the MouseRightButtonUp is called, the property which contains the selected row didn't get updated yet. Is there a event or something else after the update of the selectedRow, which tells me if the RightMouseButton got clicked?

Comment: So you need to know if the new SelectedItem was selected by a right click?

Comment: one possible scenario yes.

Comment: Hmm, I dont know how to solve it mvvm convenient. I would handle the RightButtonMouseDown event in combination with the SelectedItemChanged and RightButtonMouseUp event. In the RightButtonMouseDown I would set some flag that you can check in SelectedItemChanged and set back in RightButtonMouseUp event.